# Unable to run ascript on Apple Script Editor as an Application : Permission Denied

Tags: macos, shell

I am running a command do shell script on Apple Script Editor and I wan to save and run it as a application but while i am executing it ,I am getting a message  Permission Denied..? Tell me how to resolve it. All this I am doing on MacOsx

the command is:

```
do shell script "xxx.jar"
```

and this command was running fine while I am running it as a script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the executable bit set on the script:

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/script
```

Answer (score 1):

A `.jar` file is not a shell script; If you are trying to run the classes within the `.jar` file, then this will work provided the manifest is correctly configured within the `.jar` file:

```
do shell script "/usr/bin/java -jar xxx.jar"
```